# How to loop around wwwroot files using IDirectoryContents in .net-core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, filesystems

I want to access the locally stored files in a particular folder in my wwwroot and display them on a view.

I can see the files using the **IDirectoryContents** object but I can't see how to look around that object and access the file names.

```
    IFileProvider provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(_env.WebRootPath");
    IDirectoryContents contents = provider.GetDirectoryContents("");
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop around **IDirectoryContents** you can use the PhysicalFileInfo class.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical;

  foreach (PhysicalFileInfo myFile in contents)
    {
        string filename = myFile.Name;
    }
```